# Set customized css as top priority

Tags: css

I hava a customized `costom_css.css` to overwrite others

```
blockquote {
    font-size: 14px !important;
}
.pagination>.active>a {
  background-color: orange !important;
    border-color: orange !important;
}
```

I have to append `!important` to every single line,
Could this operation be implemented in one place?

Comment: Write more specific selectors, for example: `body .pagination > .active > a` instead of using `!important`.

Comment: I can figure out that the difference of your rule is to separate them with space, is that right?  `.pagination>.active>a` `body .pagination > .active > a` @BenM

Comment: No, please read about [specificity in CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). By prepending the selector with `body`, it becomes more specific than previous selectors for the same element.

Comment: Also, make sure to include your CSS after all other CSS files.

Comment: got it, could you please  transmit the comment to answer?  @BenM

Comment: @TDR Thanks, I've just added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using `!important`, which is notoriously bad practice and makes your codebase almost unmaintainable, you should add specificity to your selectors instead. Prepending your selectors with `body` should product more specificity to your selectors:

```
body blockquote {
    font-size: 14px;
}

body .pagination > .active > a {
    background-color: orange;
    border-color: orange;
}
```

MDN has a great article on CSS specificity, [check it out](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

It's also worth noting that you should include your own CSS files (or code) *after* any external CSS files to ensure that they cascade correctly.